# Most memory efficient way to merge two files

Tags: c#

I need to merge two files while also applying a sort. It is important the I keep the task light on memory usage. I need to create a console app in c# for this.

Input File 1:

> *Some Header*
>   A12345334
>   A00123445
>   A44566555
>   B55677
>   B55683
>   B66489
>   *record count: 6*

Input File 2:

> *Some Header*
>   A00123465
>   B99423445
>   *record count: 2*

So, I need to make sure that the third file should have all the "A" records coming first and then the "B" records followed by the Total record count.

Output File:

> *Some header*
>   A12345334
>   A00123445
>   A44566555
>   A00123465
>   B99423445
>   B55677
>   B55683
>   B66489
>   *record count: 8*

Record sorting within "A" and "B" is not relevant.

Comment: loop through the two files, extract all A records, then loop through again and extract the B's? that'd only ever keep 1 record in memory, at the cost of having to do 4 full file-scans.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and let us know if there is a specific issue you are having.  Questions like this are typically viewed as "Give me teh codez" and are frowned upon.

Comment: what's your file size like?

Comment: Someone edited your question so that the file contents were very easy to read. I can't imaging why you got rid of that edit.

Comment: are the input initially sorted?

Comment: Light on what kind of memory usage?  Page file? Physical memory? Address space? Private bytes? Shared bytes? Working set?

Answer (score 3):

Since your source files appear sorted, you can do with with very low memory usage.

Just open both input files as well as a new file for writing. Then compare the next available line from each input file and write the line that comes first to your output file. Each time you write a line to the output file, get the next line from the input file it came from.

Continue until both input files are finished.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is an issue the easiest way to do this is probably going to be to read the records from both files, store them in a SQLite or SQL Server Compact database, and execute a SELECT query that returns a sorted record set.  Make sure you have an index on the field you want to sort on.

That way, you don't have to store the records in memory, and you don't need any sorting algorithms; the database will store the records on disk and do your sorting for you.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) for this application. So you can open a file using [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx), copy all lines using [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) for file #1, then for file #2. This operations are very fast, have integrated buffers and are very lightweight.

if the input files are already sorted by A and B, you can switch between the source readers to make the output sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea, assuming the records are already sorted in the original files:

1. Start looping through file 2, collecting all A-records
2. Once you reach the first B-record, start collecting those in a separate collection.
3. Read all of File 1.
4. Write out the content of the A-records collection from file 2, then append the contents read from file 1, followed by the B-records from file 2.

Visualized:

```
<A-data from file 2>
<A-data, followed by B-data from file 1>
<B-data from file 2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about memory this is a perfect case for [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and read one line at a time from each file. If that is not an issue read the whole thing into a list and just call sort the write it out.

If you can't even keep the whole sorted list in memory then a database or memory mapped file is you best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input files are already ordered:

1. Open Input files 1 and 2 and create the Output file.
2. Read the first record from file 1. If it starts with A, write it to the output file. Continue reading from input file 1 until you reach a record that starts with B.
3. Read the first record from file 2. If it start with A, write it to the output file. Continue reading from input file 2 until you reach a record that starts with B.
4. Go back to file 1, and write the 'B' record to the output file. Continue reading from input file 1 until you reach the end of the stream.
5. Go back to file 2, and write the 'B' record to the output file. Continue reading from input file 2 until you reach the end of the stream.

This method will prevent you from ever having to hold more than 2 rows of data in memory at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two sorted sequences you just need to merge the two sequences into a single sequence, in much the same way the second half of the MergeSort algorithm works.

Unfortunately, given the interface that `IEnumerable` provides, it ends up a bit mess and copy-pasty, but it should perform quite well and use a very small memory footprint:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

    using (var secondIterator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        Wrapper<T> secondItem = null; //when the wrapper is null there are no more items in the second sequence

        if (secondIterator.MoveNext())
            secondItem = new Wrapper<T>() { Value = secondIterator.Current };
        foreach (var firstItem in first)
        {
            if (secondItem != null)
            {
                while (comparer.Compare(firstItem, secondItem.Value) > 0)
                {
                    yield return secondItem.Value;
                    if (secondIterator.MoveNext())
                        secondItem.Value = secondIterator.Current;
                    else
                        secondItem = null;
                }
            }
            yield return firstItem;

            yield return secondItem.Value;
            while (secondIterator.MoveNext())
                yield return secondIterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have a `Merge` function it's pretty trivial:

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt",
    Merge(File.ReadLines("File1.txt"), File.ReadLines("File2.txt")))
```

The File `ReadLines` and `WriteAllLines` here each utilize `IEnumerable` and will stream the lines accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source code for the more generic/boiler plate solution for merge sorting 2 files.

```
public static void Merge(string inFile1, string inFile2, string outFile) 
{
    string line1 = null;
    string line2 = null;
    using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(inFile1))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(inFile2))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outFile))
            {
                line1 = sr1.ReadLine();
                line2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                while(line1 != null && line2 != null)
                {
                    // your comparison function here
                    // ex: (line1[0] < line2[0])
                    if(line1 < line2)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line1);
                        line1 = sr1.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line2);
                        line2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                while(line1 != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line1);
                    line1 = sr1.ReadLine();
                }
                while(line2 != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line2);
                    line2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void merge_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("designation");
        dt.Columns.Add("age");
        dt.Columns.Add("year");
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\text1.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        string[] lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\text1.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = values[0].ToString();
            dr["designation"] = values[1].ToString();
            dr["age"] = values[2].ToString();
            dr["year"] = values[3].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        foreach (string line in lines1)
        {

            string[] values = line.Split(',');

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = values[0].ToString();
            dr["designation"] = values[1].ToString();
            dr["age"] = values[2].ToString();
            dr["year"] = values[3].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        grdstudents.DataSource = dt;
        grdstudents.DataBind();
}
```